# How to insert a invoice data to db in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, crud

Any one can help me how to insert a invoice data to db in codeigniter. I am beginner to development. I have no idea how to insert and how is handle database .

Answer (score 0):

Invoice table have invoice date field that field type date and default values current date you choose its automatically taking system date of your invoice date. Or

```
$invoicedate = date("Y-m-d");
$insertdata = array("invoice_date" =>$invoicedate,"invoice_amount" =>560);
$this->db->insert(insertdata);
```

Comment: insertdata = array("invoice_date" =>$invoicedate,"invoice_amount" =>560);  add multiple times

Comment: Also I need how to manage item table. I have no idea about that